# iOS cordova plugin: How to send plugin result from ios plugin to javascript in background thread

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a plugin class which is extending CDVPlugin. This plugin will invoked from a button click from HTML side. After that I am using UIImagePickerController to take two photos. Then I am trying to send those images to javascript callback function using pluginresult.

Here, as I am trying to send two images in one go, the UI is being stuck for some time. So, I want to send the result in a background thread. And also I should be receive that from javascript callback function.

Has someone done this before? Is there any way to achieve this so that UI navigation will be smoother....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    - (void)myPluginMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    // Check command.arguments here.
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        NSString* payload = nil;
        // Some blocking logic...
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:payload];
        // The sendPluginResult method is thread-safe.
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Store the plugin callback in an array, so you can send the success or error plugin result when your background task finish

Comment: Or do you want to know how to run the code on a background thread?

Comment: Ya.. Could you please tell me how to run in background thread